# Clearing quill editor after submit

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, quill

I am using vue-quill on my nuxt 3 project. I wrapped it inside a component and all is working fine but after a post request, editor still displays the content.

**AppEditor**

```
<script setup>
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css'

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  taskId: {
    type: Number,
    default: null,
  },
  initialContent: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  placeholder: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  taskmembers: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue', 'on-editor-ready'])
const editor = ref()

const toolbar = [
  [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
  ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
  [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
  ['link', 'image'],
  ['clean'],
]

const onUpdate = () => {
  const content = editor.value.getHTML()
  emit('update:modelValue', content)
}

const onEditorReady = (event) => {
  emit('on-editor-ready', event)
}

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <QuillEditor
      ref="editor"
      theme="snow"
      :toolbar="toolbar"
      content-type="html"
      :content="props.modelValue"
      placeholder="Say something..."
      @ready="onEditorReady"
      @update:content="onUpdate"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

and on my page I use it like below

**TaskComment**

```
<script setup>
import AppEditor from '@/components/AppEditor.vue'

const postComment = async () => {
  const task = props.taskId
  const url = `/tasks/${task}/comments`

  loading.value = true

  try {
    await useBaseFetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        comment: message.value,
      }),
    })

    loading.value = false
    message.value = ''

    editor.value.setContents([]) //trying to clear the content

    currentPage.value = 1
    getComments()
  } catch (error) {
    loading.value = false
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 422) {
      console.log('error', error)
    } else {
      errorMsg.value = 'An error occured.'
    }
  }
}

</script>

<template>
  <Form @submit="onSubmit">
     <AppEditor ref="editor" v-model="message" :taskmembers="members" :task-id="props.taskId" />
       <span v-if="errorMessage && meta.touched" class="text-red-500 text-sm normal-case">{{ errorMessage }}</span>
          <div class="flex gap-2 mt-4">
            <ElementsAppButton size="small" type="submit" :loading="loading">
              Save
            </ElementsAppButton>
          </div>
  </Form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

vue-quill doesn't seem to like the empty string in `message.value = ''`.

Instead, you can set it to an empty paragraph `<p></p>` or `<p><br></p>`, which is what quill uses as empty value:

```js
message.value = '<p></p>'
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)